# How do I pass a property accessor as a function argument?

Tags: javascript

I want to pass a property acessor or object literal 'key' as an argument in a function so I can use it with dot notation in a for loop.

For example:

```js
let myArray = [
{
apples: 4,
bananas: 1,
},
{
apples: 10,
bananas: 2,
},
{
apples: 4,
bananas: 3,
},
]

Array.prototype.count = function(objProperty, testValue) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i].objProperty === testValue) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count
}

console.log(myArray.count('apples', 4)) // expect: 2
console.log(myArray.count('apples', 10)) // expect: 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access an object's property like `Object.property` or `Objects[property] (in case, property is a string datatype)`

```js
let myArray = [
{
apples: 4,
bananas: 1,
},
{
apples: 10,
bananas: 2,
},
{
apples: 4,
bananas: 3,
},
]

Array.prototype.count = function(arrayProperty, testValue) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < this.length; ++i) {
    if (this[i][arrayProperty] === testValue) {
      count++;
    }
  }
  return count
}

console.log(myArray.count('apples', 4)) // expect: 2
console.log(myArray.count('apples', 10)) // expect: 1
```